# Javascript validation not working, but PHP validation does

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

Case: Php and Javascript validation for Signup Form

So, I am stuck with this problem :
I  have a Sign Up page and I validate it using Javascript and PHP.
When I have no PHP validation script, the Javascript validation is working fine. However,  after I added PHP validation for the username (to check whether the username exists in the database or no), the javascript validation doesn't work, but the PHP validation works fine.

I include the javascript validation named 'validate.js' in the index file (at head tag)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate.js"></script>
```

Here is the signup.php file

```
<?php
    //check if there is 'error' in the url (from signup_process.php)
    $error = isset($_GET['error']) ? $_GET['error'] : "";
?>

<div class="col s12">
    <h3 class="center">Sign Up</h3>

    <form action="<?php echo BASE_URL."signup_process.php"; ?>" onsubmit="return validate();" method="POST">
        <label class="active" for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="validate">
        <div class="error" id="erremail"></div>


        <label class="active" for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        <div class="error" id="errusername"></div>
        <?php if($error=="username") echo "<div class='error'>Username already exists</div>"; //if error exists (from signup_process.php) ?> 


        <label class="active" for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        <div class="error" id="errpass"></div>


        <label class="active" for="re-password">Retype Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="re-password" id="re-password">
        <div class="error" id="errrepass"></div>

        <div class="center">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue lighten-2" type="submit" name="submit">Sign Up
                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

After the user entered all the data and validated by javascript, then the data will go to 'signup_process.php', here's the code

```
<?php
    include_once("function/helper.php");
    include_once("function/connect.php");

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, md5($_POST['password']));

    //check if username exists
    $cekUsername = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'");

    //unset password so it doesn't show up in the url if the username exists
    unset($_POST['password']);
    //show email and username in url if username exists
    $data = http_build_query($_POST);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($cekUsername) == 1){ //if username exists, show the form data in the url to get validated by php at signup.php
        header("location: ".BASE_URL."index.php?page=signup&error=username&$data");
    }else{ //signup success
        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO user (username, password, email, display_name) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$username')");

        //Set code for email verif
        $code = rand(3010, 9753);

        //Parameter for email verif
        $to = $email;
        $subject = "Email Verification Code for Daforums";
        $message = "Your activation code is " . $code ;
        $header = "from : no-reply@daforums.xyz";
        mail('lionel.ritchie@yahoo.com',$subject,$message,$header);

        header("location: ".BASE_URL."index.php?page=login");
    }
?>
```

The javascript validation script 'validate.js' :

```
function validate(){
    let result = true;

    let username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    let errusername = document.getElementById('errusername');
    let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    let erremail = document.getElementById('erremail');
    let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    let errpass = document.getElementById('errpass');
    let repassword = document.getElementById('re-password').value;
    let errrepass = document.getElementById('errrepass');

    const emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
    const usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/;

    //Email
    if(email == ""){
        erremail.innerHTML  = "Email can't be empty";
        result = false;
    else if(!emailRegex.test(email)) {
        erremail.innerHTML = "Invalid e-mail format";
        result = false;
    }else{
        erremail.innerHTML = "";
    }

    // Username
    if(username == ""){
        errusername.innerHTML = "Username can't be empty";
        result = false;
    }else if(!usernameRegex.test(username)) {
        errusername.innerHTML = "Username must only contain alphanumeric characters";
        result = false;
    }else if(username.length < 6 || username.length > 20) {
        errusername.innerHTML = "Username must be between 6 and 20 characters long";
        result = false;
    }else{
        errusername.innerHTML = "";
    }

    //Password
    if(password==""){
        errpass.innerHTML = "Password can't be empty";
        result = false;
    }else if (password.length < 8){
        errpass.innerHTML = "Password must be at least 8 characters long";
        result = false;
    }else if (password != repassword){
        errrepass.innerHTML = "Please correctly confirm the password";
        result = false;
    }else{
        errpass.innerHTML = "";
        errrepass.innerHTML = "";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Before the php validation in signup.php was added, the javascript validation works fine.
(So if if remove the code below, the javascript validation will work).
the php validation is located in signup.php pages above, here is the code:

```
<?php
    //check if there is 'error' in the url (from signup_process.php)
    $error = isset($_GET['error']) ? $_GET['error'] : "";
?>
```

```
<?php if($error=="username") echo "<div class='error'>Username already exists</div>"; //if error exists (from signup_process.php) ?>
```

I've been searching for this problem but nothing matched my problems. Any help will be appreciated ^^, Thank you.

Comment: Where are you calling validate function?

Comment: In the form tag in signup.php, <form onsubmit="return validate();" > @Clystian

Comment: when you validate function is wrong or inside fails, you can use try catch and no propagate errors on page (JS), check developer console of browser

Comment: You realize your entire code is unsafe. Don't store plain text passwords and do use a prepared statement and password_hash().

Answer (score 0):

hey its have nothing between php query parameter and js validation
but i have find one thing in your js code

```
//Email
if(email == ""){
    erremail.innerHTML  = "Email can't be empty";
    result = false;
else if(!emailRegex.test(email)) {
    erremail.innerHTML = "Invalid e-mail format";
    result = false;
}else{
    erremail.innerHTML = "";
}
```

in this portion of your validation you forgot to add closing brackets of if condition
add closing bracket and check code like this

```
//Email
if(email == ""){
    erremail.innerHTML  = "Email can't be empty";
    result = false;
}else if(!emailRegex.test(email)) {
    erremail.innerHTML = "Invalid e-mail format";
    result = false;
}else{
    erremail.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I have already added it and nothing changes. I still couldn't figure out what's wrong

Comment: @darrow29 did you try debug with Chrome Developer Tools? Check console? IT say what was error in JS

Answer (score 0):

@bharat savani and @ChandraShekar were right about javascript

it just was close if bracket in email validation

Run this snippet I works Ok

You really can be problems with your enviroments if you dont get the changes

so you mark [wrong] two good answer, be careful next time.

```js
function validate() {
    let result = true;

    let username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    let errusername = document.getElementById('errusername');
    let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    let erremail = document.getElementById('erremail');
    let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    let errpass = document.getElementById('errpass');
    let repassword = document.getElementById('re-password').value;
    let errrepass = document.getElementById('errrepass');

    const emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
    const usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/;

    //Email
    if (email == "") {
        erremail.innerHTML = "Email can't be empty";
        result = false;
    } else if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
        erremail.innerHTML = "Invalid e-mail format";
        result = false;
    } else {
        erremail.innerHTML = "";
    }

    // Username
    if (username == "") {
        errusername.innerHTML = "Username can't be empty";
        result = false;
    } else if (!usernameRegex.test(username)) {
        errusername.innerHTML = "Username must only contain alphanumeric characters";
        result = false;
    } else if (username.length < 6 || username.length > 20) {
        errusername.innerHTML = "Username must be between 6 and 20 characters long";
        result = false;
    } else {
        errusername.innerHTML = "";
    }

    //Password
    if (password == "") {
        errpass.innerHTML = "Password can't be empty";
        result = false;
    } else if (password.length < 8) {
        errpass.innerHTML = "Password must be at least 8 characters long";
        result = false;
    } else if (password != repassword) {
        errrepass.innerHTML = "Please correctly confirm the password";
        result = false;
    } else {
        errpass.innerHTML = "";
        errrepass.innerHTML = "";
    }

    return result;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="col s12">
    <h3 class="center">Sign Up</h3>

<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validate()"
 method="POST">
        <label class="active" for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="validate">
        <div class="error" id="erremail"></div>


        <label class="active" for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        <div class="error" id="errusername"></div>

        <label class="active" for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        <div class="error" id="errpass"></div>


        <label class="active" for="re-password">Retype Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="re-password" id="re-password">
        <div class="error" id="errrepass"></div>

        <div class="center"> 
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue lighten-2 btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Sign Up 
                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
function validate() {
    let result = true;

    let username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    let errusername = document.getElementById('errusername');
    let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    let erremail = document.getElementById('erremail');
    let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    let errpass = document.getElementById('errpass');
    let repassword = document.getElementById('re-password').value;
    let errrepass = document.getElementById('errrepass');

    const emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
    const usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/;

    //Email
    if (email == "") {
        erremail.innerHTML = "Email can't be empty";
        result = false;
    } else if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
        erremail.innerHTML = "Invalid e-mail format";
        result = false;
    } else {
        erremail.innerHTML = "";
    }

    // Username
    if (username == "") {
        errusername.innerHTML = "Username can't be empty";
        result = false;
    } else if (!usernameRegex.test(username)) {
        errusername.innerHTML = "Username must only contain alphanumeric characters";
        result = false;
    } else if (username.length < 6 || username.length > 20) {
        errusername.innerHTML = "Username must be between 6 and 20 characters long";
        result = false;
    } else {
        errusername.innerHTML = "";
    }

    //Password
    if (password == "") {
        errpass.innerHTML = "Password can't be empty";
        result = false;
    } else if (password.length < 8) {
        errpass.innerHTML = "Password must be at least 8 characters long";
        result = false;
    } else if (password != repassword) {
        errrepass.innerHTML = "Please correctly confirm the password";
        result = false;
    } else {
        errpass.innerHTML = "";
        errrepass.innerHTML = "";
    }

    return result;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi your code has one issue, you have missed the closing bracket(}) in your js code at email validation line(59).

```
function validate(){

let result = true;

let username = document.getElementById('username').value;
let errusername = document.getElementById('errusername');
let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
let erremail = document.getElementById('erremail');
let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
let errpass = document.getElementById('errpass');
let repassword = document.getElementById('re-password').value;
let errrepass = document.getElementById('errrepass');

const emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
const usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/;

//Email
if(email == ""){
    erremail.innerHTML  = "Email can't be empty";
    result = false;
    }//(59 you have missed this)
else if(!emailRegex.test(email)) {
    erremail.innerHTML = "Invalid e-mail format";
    result = false;
}else{
    erremail.innerHTML = "";
}

// Username
if(username == ""){
    errusername.innerHTML = "Username can't be empty";
    result = false;
}else if(!usernameRegex.test(username)) {
    errusername.innerHTML = "Username must only contain alphanumeric characters";
    result = false;
}else if(username.length < 6 || username.length > 20) {
    errusername.innerHTML = "Username must be between 6 and 20 characters long";
    result = false;
}else{
    errusername.innerHTML = "";
}

//Password
if(password==""){
    errpass.innerHTML = "Password can't be empty";
    result = false;
}else if (password.length < 8){
    errpass.innerHTML = "Password must be at least 8 characters long";
    result = false;
}else if (password != repassword){
    errrepass.innerHTML = "Please correctly confirm the password";
    result = false;
}else{
    errpass.innerHTML = "";
    errrepass.innerHTML = "";
}

return result;
```

}

Now you can use above code, and it will works.